# Adjust text position in sidebar of shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I have this shiny dashboard and I want to move the text a little bit to the right in order to start from the same position as the radioButtons.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# Define UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "My Shiny Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    radioButtons("d23", "Display on:",
                 choices = c("2D","3D"),
                 selected = "2D"),
    # Place the uiOutput inside the sidebar
    uiOutput("minmax")
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$minmax <- renderUI({
    # Use renderText inside uiOutput
    textOutput("minmax_text")
  })
  
  output$minmax_text <- renderText({
    
    paste("Minimum for Selected Topics:", "23",
          "Maximum for Selected Topics:", "34"
    )
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The padding of the radio button group are set via the class `shiny-input-container`. Hence, one option to align your `textOutput` with the radio buttons would be to wrap it in a `div` with the same class:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$minmax <- renderUI({
    tags$div(
      class = "shiny-input-container",
      textOutput("minmax_text")  
    )
  })

  output$minmax_text <- renderText({
    paste(
      "Minimum for Selected Topics:", "23",
      "Maximum for Selected Topics:", "34"
    )
  })
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can use CSS styling:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "My Shiny Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    radioButtons("d23", "Display on:",
                 choices = c("2D","3D"),
                 selected = "2D"),
    uiOutput("minmax")
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$minmax <- renderUI({
    div(style = "padding-left: 15px;", 
        textOutput("minmax_text"))
  })
  
  output$minmax_text <- renderText({
    paste("Minimum for Selected Topics:", "23",
          "Maximum for Selected Topics:", "34")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]